# MySQL Subquery Optimization with shared subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

From these tables I have written this subquery and its giving results as per requirements.

Needs expert guidence to improve this query or if we can also be able to use join for these tables.

Query:

```
select ps,st from pac where con in (select 
config from config where logi in 
( select id from logicalnode where physi 
in (select id from ysicalnode where mas =11)));
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `exists`:

```
select payloadstr,starttime from packetdb.packet p
where exists(select 1 from packetdb.configuration c
             where p.configid = id
             and exists(select 1 from packetdb.logicalnode l
                          where c.logicalnodeid = id
                          and exists(select 1 from packetdb.physicalnode
                                     where macaddress = 117769729
                                     and l.physicalnodeid = id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    payloadstr
    ,starttime
FROM packetdb.packet
INNER JOIN packetdb.configuration
    ON packetdb.packet.configid = packetdb.configuration.idconfig
INNER JOIN packetdb.logicalnode
    ON packetdb.configuration.idconfig = packetdb.logicalnode.id
INNER JOIN packetdb.physicalnode
    ON packetdb.logicalnode.physicalnodeid = packetdb.physicalnode.id and packetdb.physicalnode.macaddress=117769729
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22773617).

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using `JOIN`

```
select payloadstr,starttime 
    from packetdb.packet a inner join packetdb.configuration b on a.configid=b.idconfig
    inner join packetdb.logicalnode c on logicalnodeid=c.id
    inner join packetdb.physicalnode d on physicalnodeid=d.id
    where macaddress =117769729
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    select pa,sta 
    from 
   pack p
    INNER JOIN
  confi c
    ON
    p.confi = c.idco
    INNER JOIN
   logice l
    ON
    c.logic = l.id
    INNER JOIN
  physiode pn
    ON
    l.physicalnodeid  = pn.id
    WHERE macaddress =123
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Left join`

```
select payloadstr,starttime 
from packet 
left join Configuration on Configuration.IDconfig = packet.configID
left join logicalnode on logicalnode.ID = Configuration.logicalnodeid
left join physicalnode on physicalnode.ID = logicalnode.physicalnodeid
 where macaddress =117769729
```